# Javascript error detection - webkit/chrome

Tags: javascript, console, webkit, google-chrome-devtools, bug-reporting

I am writing an in-app bug reporting solution for users testing my web app (PHP/jQuery). The ideal solution is simple – user-written short description of a bug and sort of javascript error dump (eg. extended javascript error visible in Chrome's console). So, that's the background, now the question is:

**Is there a way to detect javascript errors using the console, or some sort of callbacks?** It even doesn't have to be browser independent – could be narrowed to Webkit, or just to Google Chrome. Just any way to check if there was a javascript error and then to include it in the bug report.

Comment: Checkout `window.onerror`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look of [this tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). It's aboud debugging javascript with Google Chrome.

Comment: Do you really expect his test users to use that?